# Reading and Writing Text files with UTF-16LE encoding and Apache Commons IO

Tags: java, c#, utf-16le

I have written an application in Java and duplicated it in C#.  The application reads and writes text files with tab delimited data to be used by an HMI software. The HMI software requires UTF or ANSI encoding for the degree symbol to be displayed correctly or I would just use ASCII which seems to work fine.  The C# application can open files saved by either with no problem.  The java application reads files it saved perfectly but there is a small problem that crops up when reading the files saved with C#.  It throws a numberformatexception when parsing the first character in the file to and int.  This character is always a "1".  I have opened both files up with editpadlight and they appear to be identical even when viewed with encoding and the encoding is UTF-16LE.  I'm racking my brain on this, any help would be appreciated.

```
lines = FileUtils.readLines(file, "UTF-16LE");

Integer.parseInt(line[0])
```

I cannot see any difference between the file saved in C# and the one saved in Java

[Screen Shot of Data in EditPad Lite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DEit.png)

```
        if(lines.get(0).split("\\t")[0].length() == 2){
        lines.set(0, lines.get(0).substring(1));
    }
```

Comment: I was able to kludge a solution by stripping out the first character in the text file.  I'm not sure what character it is or why it is there, I've learned more about character encoder than I ever wanted to know.  With the C# version I am using Convert.ToInt16() so maybe it handles it where Java's Integer.parseInt() fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your .NET code is probably writing a BOM. Compliant readers of Unicode, strip off any BOM since it is meta-data, not part of the text data.

Your Java code explicitly specifies the byte order

```
FileUtils.readLines(file, "UTF-16LE");
```

It's somewhat of a Catch-22; If the source has a BOM then you *can* read it as "UTF-16". If it doesn't then you *can* read it as "UTF-16LE" or "UTF-16BE" as you know which it is.

So, either write it with a BOM and read it without specifying the byte order, or, write it without a BOM and read it specifying the byte order.

With a BOM:

[C#]

```
File.WriteAllLines(file, lines, Encoding.Unicode);
```

[Java]

```
FileUtils.readLines(file, "UTF-16");
```

Without a BOM:

[C#]

```
File.WriteAllLines(file, lines, new UnicodeEncoding(false));
```

[Java]

```
FileUtils.readLines(file, "UTF-16LE");
```

Comment: Thanks Tom.  In C# I was using StreamWriter and specifying Encoding.Unicode which I guess includes a byte mark.  I changed to "new UnicodeEncoding(false, false))" and it works fine

Answer (score 1):

In my java code I read the file normally, I just specified char encoding into the InputStreamReader

```
    File file = new File(fileName);
    InputStreamReader fis = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-16LE");

    br = new BufferedReader(fis);

    String line = br.readLine();
```